# beforeSave causes Queries to return nothing

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I have a cloud function that takes in a request and creates objects as well as associates them in a chain of promises. Without a beforeSave this function works fine but the beforeSave exists to prevent duplicate entries of email addresses in the Email Class.

REQUEST

```
{
   "projectDescription": "Testing saveProject",
   "projectTitle": "This is only a test, in the event of a real post          this will have an actual description",
   "isEmailEnabled": true,
   "shareEmails": [
     "test1@gmail.com",
     "test2@gmail.com",
     "test3@gmail.com"
   ],
 "userId": "1234"
}
```

FUNCTION

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveProject", function(request, response) {

    var emails = request.params.shareEmails;
    var user = request.params.userId;
    var projectDescription = request.params.projectDescription;
    var projectTitle = request.params.projectTitle;
    var emailStatus = request.params.isEmailEnabled;

    var ProjectClass = Parse.Object.extend("Project");

    var EmailsClass = Parse.Object.extend("Email");

    var EmailsClassAssignment = Parse.Object.extend("EmailAssignment");

    var project = new ProjectClass();

    var projectO;

    var emailQueryArray;

    project.set("title", projectTitle);
    project.set("createdBy", {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": user
    });
    project.set("description", projectDescription);
    project.set("status", true);
    project.set("emailShareEnabled", emailStatus);
    project.save().then(function(projectObject) {

        projectO = projectObject;
    }).then(function() {
        emails.forEach(function(emailAddress) {
            var email = new EmailsClass();

            email.set("address", emailAddress);
            email.save();
        });
    }).then(function() {

        emails.forEach(function(emailQuery) {
            var queryEmail = new Parse.Query("Email");

            queryEmail.equalTo("address", emailQuery);
            queryEmail.find().then(function(results) {
                emailObject = results;
                console.log(emailObject);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

beforeSave Code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Email", function(request, response) {

var query = new Parse.Query("Email");


// Gets the email key value (string) before object is saved
query.equalTo("address", request.object.get("address"));

// Checks to see if an object for that email already exists
query.first({

  success: function(object) {
    if (object) {
        response.error("This email already exisits");
    } else {
      response.success();
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    response.error("Could not determine if this email exists");
  }
});
});
```

Is there a way to account for the beforeSave in the callback from saving the email object so that I ensure the object is there to query against?

I need the objects to be there so that I can get the Id for each and create a pointer in the Email assignments Class.

Would be happy to further explain any part of the code or function as a whole.

Comment: Another question I have is if its worth checking for duplicates right in the cloud function rather than with a beforeSave in order to control the order as well as allow that object to be there before I query for its Id. Are there any performance issues with this and is it scalable still?

Comment: I don't see any `beforeSave` or duplicate checking in your code. Am I just not understanding?

Comment: @JLRishe I added the beforeSave code under the cloud function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` is, just like `find`, an asynchronous method. To wait until it they have completed, and to notice whether they have failed, you need to use `Promise.when` on all the promises that have been created in the loop. See [Parse JavaScript Promises within Loop not Completing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28523313/1048572) and similar questions.

Your code should look like this:

```
var ProjectClass = Parse.Object.extend("Project");
var EmailsClass = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
var EmailsClassAssignment = Parse.Object.extend("EmailAssignment");

Parse.Cloud.define("saveProject", function(request, response) {
    var emails = request.params.shareEmails;
    var user = request.params.userId;
    var projectDescription = request.params.projectDescription;
    var projectTitle = request.params.projectTitle;
    var emailStatus = request.params.isEmailEnabled;

    var project = new ProjectClass();
    project.set("title", projectTitle);
    project.set("createdBy", {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": user
    });
    project.set("description", projectDescription);
    project.set("status", true);
    project.set("emailShareEnabled", emailStatus);
    project.save().then(function() {
        return Parse.Promise.when(emails.map(function(emailAddress) {
//      ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^
            var email = new EmailsClass();
            email.set("address", emailAddress);
            return email.save();
//          ^^^^^^
        }));
    }).then(function() {
        return Parse.Promise.when(emails.map(function(emailQuery) {
//      ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^
            var queryEmail = new Parse.Query("Email");
            queryEmail.equalTo("address", emailQuery);
            return queryEmail.find().then(function(results) {
//          ^^^^^^
                console.log(results);
            });
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to using promises as well as Parse so this was a great lesson in both subjects!