# Pass exisiting Object from Parse Class otherwise create a new object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

As of right now I have a beforeSave function that prevents duplicate emails from being saved shown below.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Email", function(request, response) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Email");


// Gets the email key value (string) before object is saved
    query.equalTo("address", request.object.get("address"));

// Checks to see if an object for that email already exists
    query.first({

        success: function(object) {
          if (object) {
             response.error("Email already Exists");
          } else {
             response.success();
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
      response.error("Could not determine if this email exists");
       }
    });
});
```

Function that creates emails but if someone adds an email address to their project that we have saved before this will break the function and ultimately the chain of promises that this function exists in, at least in my understanding.

```
function createEmails(emails) {
    var EmailsClass = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
    var toSave = _.map(emails, function(emailAddress) {
        var email = new EmailsClass();
        email.set("address", emailAddress);
        return email;
    });

    return Parse.Object.saveAll(toSave);
}
```

Comment: Is is worth it to simply do the duplicate check inside the function and not use a beforeSave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully somebody has a better answer than this, but it seems that the only way to avoid saving on `beforeSave` is to respond with an error, and that flummoxes subsequent processing.

So, if attempting to create a duplicate is not an error from an application point of view, just a condition to be disallowed, then I think you must catch that before `beforeSave`, by filtering the input for duplicates.

That's not so pretty when creating in bulk, but it would go something like this:

```
// answer a promise for an existing email object with address==email or a promise to save a new one
function fetchOrCreateEmail(emailAddress) {
    var EmailsClass = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
    var query = new Parse.Query(EmailsClass);
    query.equalTo("address", emailAddress);
    return query.first().then(function(object) {
        if (!object) {
            object = new EmailsClass();
            object("address", emailAddress);
            return object.save();
        } else {
            return Parse.Promise.as(object);
        }
    });
}

// create Email objects with a given array of addresses, creating
// objects only for unique addresses
function createEmails(emails) {
    var toSave = _.map(emails, fetchOrCreateEmail);
    return Parse.Promise.when(toSave);
}
```

With this `fetchOrCreateEmail` function, you can create in batch as shown, or create a single like this:

```
fetchOrCreateEmail(emailAddress);
```

If you use these for all creation of Email objects, you'll no longer need (or want) the `beforeSave` hook for that class.  I'd like to find out if there's a better solution than this one, but I think that's the best that can be done at present.

Comment: I would strongly recommend moving away from `beforeSave` handlers as they cause timeout issues and there's the problem of having to throw an error to stop the save. I now use Cloud Functions to save, they get 15 seconds to run, can take as much/little input as I like, perform more complex logic, handle errors better and return data in any format I like.

Comment: I tried to drop this into the original chain of promises you helped me with and am getting not defined errors. Do I need to alter my promises chain from preview question in order to implement this?

Comment: Just found a coding error in my suggestion.  Fixed it on the line marked "did edit here".  Apologies.  (and apologies in advance if I missed other mistakes).  Hard to test parse stuff for others without a lot of effort recreating their database.

Comment: Fixed! It is now saying that I have a typeError on `return object.isNew();` it says [object Object] has no method isNew. Do I need to make it `return object[0].isNew();` or provide some sort of dynamic index?

Comment: Nope.  That's my mistake again.  Editing now.

Comment: Okay, I had complicated matters by trying to illustrate how you could select for new objects (isNew()) and save those selectively.  The simpler code immediately saves new "Email" objects or returns existing ones.

Comment: One last issue, I am using the chain that you wrote in the previous question untouched and it works up until the createEmailClassAssignments section and gives me this error "There was an error saving invalid type for key email, expected *Email, but got map" I console.logged what is being passed from this block and it only passes one object on. If you have time could you possibly explain how I would implement this into the chain I have and I can plug away at that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74127/discussion-between-mcclaskiem-and-danh).