# Javascript with Parse - Saving with Ansynchronous Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, pointers, parse-platform

I'm saving three results but they are all the same. I'm running into the dam Javascript async loop problem. How do I get out of this?

my code:

```
 var teamMatch = function(){
     var Pairingteam = [];
     var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
     var x = matchedPairingIds.length;
     while (x--) {
         var match = matchedPairingIds[x];
         var matching = function () {
             matched.set("team", {
               __type: "Pointer",
               className: "_User",
               objectId: "yCDDEWoiwM"
               });
             matched.set("Pairing", {
              __type: "Pointer",
              className: "Pairing",
              objectId: match
              });
             Pairingteam.push(matched.save());
            }
          }
          promise.then(function(){
            return Parse.Promise.when(Pairingteam);
          });
      }
     teamMatch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was that I hoisted the matched class.  Matched needs to be defined within the loop.  The code should look like this:

```
var teamMatch = function(){
     var Pairingteam = [];
     var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
     var x = matchedPairingIds.length;
     while (x--) {
         var matched = new Parse.Object("Matched"); //THIS IS THE MISSING PIECE
         var match = matchedPairingIds[x];
         var matching = function () {
             matched.set("team", {
               __type: "Pointer",
               className: "_User",
               objectId: "yCDDEWoiwM"
               });
             matched.set("Pairing", {
              __type: "Pointer",
              className: "Pairing",
              objectId: match
              });
             Pairingteam.push(matched.save());
            }
          }
          promise.then(function(){
            return Parse.Promise.when(Pairingteam);
          });
      }
     teamMatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `matched.save();` is an asynchronous operation. Most likely your function is returning before all the saves are complete. Your best bet to overcome this is to use promises. Read up on them here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises

Then take a look at [Parse JavaScript SDK and Promise Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723121/parse-javascript-sdk-and-promise-chaining) and [Multiple Queries Parse Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708651/multiple-queries-parse-javascript/28710096#28710096)

Adapting the above solutions to your question would look something like this:

```
 var partnerMatch = function() {
 var savePromises = [];  // this will collect save promises 

// Create a trivial resolved promise as a base case.
 var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
 var x = matchArray.length // x = 3
 while (x--) {
     var matched = matchArray[x];
     var matching = function() {
         matched.set("partner", {
             __type: "Pointer",
             className: "_User",
             objectId: "yCDDEWoiwM"
         });
         matched.set("match", match);
         savePromises.push(matched.save());
     }
 }

 promise.then(function(){
   // now do the saves
   return Parse.Promise.when(savePromises);
 });
 }
 partnerMatch();
```

Promise.When(); waits around until all of the promises passed to it are resolved.

EDIT

I'm not sure where your `matched` variable is coming from, but here's the updated code

```
 var teamMatch = function(){
 var Pairingteam = [];
 var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
 var x = matchedPairingIds.length;
 while (x--) {
     var match = matchedPairingIds[x];
     matched.set("team", {
       __type: "Pointer",
       className: "_User",
       objectId: "yCDDEWoiwM"
       });
     matched.set("Pairing", {
      __type: "Pointer",
      className: "Pairing",
      objectId: match
      });
     Pairingteam.push(matched.save());
     }
      promise.then(function(){
        return Parse.Promise.when(Pairingteam);
      });
  }
 teamMatch();
```

Comment: A little extra detail about where I put it or how to implement? Do you mean 'then'? I'm familiar with 'then' but I don't know how to implement it in this case. I'm looking up Promise.When();

Comment: I'm definitely getting promises and 3 of them as I'd expect from the savePromises array you proposed. Unfortunately it is still only saving one of these values.

Comment: Updated to include base promise

Comment: The Parse SDK is completely useless. I see the other illustrations and they're somewhat instructive but I'm not connecting the dots. The Promise.when() is a nice little trick but the example you show and the ones illustrated in the examples you provide are saving 3 identical in the array and only one parse object instead of 3 unique Parse.Objects.

Comment: Ok, it feels like I'm getting closer but now I'm getting no results in the array. I'm thinking that maybe I need to call the matching(); function? I appreciate the guidance here . . . one more step please?

Comment: I updated the code to where I'm at now. I'm receiving no results in my array with this code.

Comment: Thanks for chiming back.  If I mentioned it, I tried it already and that still gives me 3 identical promises and which should be 3 rows in the matched class but it is only one row.  To be clear it should be 3 different promises in the array and 3 different rows upon the save.

Comment: thanks for circling back on this. matched is the new Parse.Object I want to save the pointer pairs to. In this example there are 3 pointer pairs as x = 3. Only one is saving based on the code your providing. And all of the promises in the Pairingteam array are identical.

Comment: Are you successfully getting the proper match from your matchedPairingIds? How do you know the promises are identical? Where are you declaring `var matched = new Parse.Object`? I'm having a hard time diagnosing your problem.

Comment: I hoisted var matched = new Parse Object. I'm sure of the matched PairIds, I don't much but anything I do know comes from console.log("he he").  But you're right, I don't know if the promises are identical - I got that confused with the identical array results I would get from before.